# I'm having windows server errors

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, iis

I have recently started using **Windows Server** to host my personal WebDev Library on it but whenever I try to connect to it using my **Win10 PC** it takes me to [**this Site**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZ02W.jpg)

And in my **Windows Server**, my configurations are [**like this**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fjLJY.png).

Can someone please help me.

***Update***

My Website works on the server but not on my **Win10 PC** [**Image**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2AWA7.png).

Comment: It would be helpful if you could show your relevant DNS lookup zone(s) (internal and, if applicable, external). Also, the screenshot of your IIS settings doesn't actually show any of your settings. How do the bindings look compared to the DNS record(s) for the service?

Comment: @MikaelH The requirements you have asked for are **[here](https://imgur.com/a/MgApugw)**. It would be great if you'd help me.

Comment: @Arib.Glitch Do you actually own the webdevlibrary.com domain?

Comment: @Ryan Bolger what do you mean by that I own webdevlibrary.com.

Comment: GoDaddy claims it is available for sale. https://www.godaddy.com/domainsearch/find?checkAvail=1&tmskey=&domainToCheck=webdevlibrary.com

Comment: But it's for $10,000

Comment: The domain is premium